# How can I get a multi-colored object in the solid viewport display like in this Joey Carlino Tutorial?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, sculpting, faces

I'm very new to Blender and I stumbled upon this tutorial [Faces are EASY with this trick - Blender tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QoLorR9qpY) by Joey Carlino.

It's a very good tutorial and he explains everything well (I watched it beforehand). But now that I'm trying to follow, I get stuck at the part where he adds the subdivision modifier. Instead of looking like this:

[image]

I get something like this:

[image]

I did some viewport settings tweaking (not really knowing what I'm doing lol) and I ended up with the following:

[image]

As you can imagine it's still hard to follow the tutorial if the face is all morphed and I can barely see what I'm working on.

Can you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Hello it looks like you have overlapping faces, maybe select all in Edit mode and try a M > Merge by Distance? Or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: As moonboots said, it seems that you have got overlapping faces. But I also think that you have got an extra cube or something. Check the outliner (that side panel thingy where you see all the objects present in the scene) and see if there isn't an extra cube. Coz I replicated a similar thing with an extra cube: https://i.imgur.com/MC8azGj.png

Comment: Hi, Yes, there's an extra cube, the tutorial said to replicate it. I noticed I had my visibility filters incorrect on the second duplicated object, and fixing that did the trick! Thank you all.